# How to create Android bitmap from RGBA buffer in native code?

Tags: android, performance, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm having BMP as RGBA buffer (i'm able to save it as BMP in native code and view it as .bmp image) and i need to pass it to android from native code. I've found similar questions and answers and this is one of the solutions:

1. create android bitmap object in android
2. pass it to native code
3. set pixels buffer in native code
4. return bitmap back to android side

This is not suitable for me because:

1. pixels array is created i native code
2. if i create it on android side with specified width and height this makes android allocate the second buffer and it's not good as i'm going to have 24 bitmaps a second (streaming video).

I need smth like this:

1. pass Buffer from native code and Bitmap.createFromBuffer(Buffer buffer, int width, int height, int format)
2. create android bitmap object in native code, set pixels buffer and return back to android

Any suggestions/thoughts?

Comment: How about saving it to SD card as .jpg and the reading it again?

Comment: this can be solution but i'm not sure it's good for mobile devices to save frames for streaming video

Comment: Usually streaming video involves YUV buffers. YUV to RGBA conversion is quite expensive (same order of CPU resources as used by software h264 decoder, much more than what is spent to run the HW decoder). Conversion of YUV to RGB may be improved with renderscript or OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna to create java Bitmap object from native code, you should do something like this:

in native code read your buffer, then apply every pixel in bufer to argb format, if you have rgba, you can do something like this:

```
int a = 0xFF & yourPixelInt;
int r = 0xFF & yourPixelInt >> 24;
int g = 0xFF & yourPixelInt >> 16;
int b = 0xFF & yourPixelInt >> 8;
unsigned int newPixel = (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | (b)
```

Do it for all pixels to convert it from rgba to argb, after that you can create java Bitmap from native code:

```
jint* bytes = env->GetIntArrayElements( array, NULL );
if (bytes != NULL) {
    memcpy(bytes, buffer, origBufferSize * sizeof (unsigned int));
    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements( array, bytes, 0 );
}

jclass bitmapClass = env->FindClass("android/graphics/Bitmap");
jmethodID methodid = env->GetStaticMethodID(bitmapClass, "createBitmap", "([IIIIILandroid/graphics/Bitmap$Config;)Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;");

jclass bitmapConfig = env->FindClass("android/graphics/Bitmap$Config");
jfieldID argb8888FieldID = env->GetStaticFieldID(bitmapConfig, "ARGB_8888",
    "Landroid/graphics/Bitmap$Config;");
jobject argb8888Obj = env->GetStaticObjectField(bitmapConfig, argb8888FieldID);

jobject java_bitmap = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(bitmapClass, methodid, array, 0, bitmapwidth, bitmapwidth, bitmapheight, argb8888Obj);
```

Don't forget to release objects to avoid memory leak

```
env->DeleteLocalRef(array);
env->DeleteLocalRef(bitmapClass);
env->DeleteLocalRef(bitmapConfig);
env->DeleteLocalRef(argb8888Obj);
```